# Can we say that the complexity of algorithm below is exactly O(lgn)

Tags: string, int, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I wrote a function to convert an integer to a string. can we say that the complexity of this algorithm is exactly O(lgn) ?, because  the number of characters in the input string exactly lgn + 1.

```
char* int_to_str(int n)
{
    int size = 0;
    bool is_neg = false;
    int m = n;
    if (n < 0)
    {
        is_neg = true;
        m = n - (n << 1);
    }
    int k = m;
    while(k > 0)
    {
        k /= 10;
        ++size;
    }
    char* out;
    if(is_neg)
    {
        out = new char[++size];
    }
    else
    {
        out = new char[size];
    }
    int i = size;
    out[i] = '\0';
    while(m > 0 && i >= 0)
    {
        out[--i] = (char)((m % 10) + '0');
        m /= 10;        
    }
    if(is_neg)
    {
        out[0] = '-';
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: The algorithm is linear, O(d), where d is the number of digits used for n. Complexity is always measured in input size, not in input value. The size of an integer is its bit length, which would become more pronounced if you were using big integers.

Comment: @LutzL: not necessarily, it can be measured in anything. Think of the complexity of the Euclidean algorithm, rated in terms of the input values rather than input size (trivially `O(1)` !). The output size can also enter into play. There are many other examples.

Comment: If you want to compare complexity classes of different algorithms, the only unifying principle is size of input vs. run time. I think that in such a context the complexity of Euclids algorithm, especially of big integer variants and more efficient variants like Lehmers algorithm, will always be given in terms of digits or bits of the input. Of course, the size of the output gives a lower bound of the complexity, since every bit of it has to be written during the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your question is about `O(lg(N))` vs `lg(N)+1`.

You need to go back to [the definition of big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

It states that any function that is an upper bound of the running time for sufficiently large values of the argument, and multiplied by a suitable constant can be used.

You can easily check that `lg(N)+1` is `O(lg(N))` or `O(log(N))` [base 10] or `O(ln(N))` [base `e`] or `O(lg(N)+1)` or `O(lg(N)/4+1000/N)` or `O(Hn)` [harmonic numbers] ...

You also have that `lg(N)+1` is `O(N)` or `O(N^2)` or `O(N!)`... but these bounds are not tight.

Answer (score 0):

O(lg(N)) is the same as O(lg(N) + 1), just that the constant differs.

g(x) = O(f(x)) means that there exist constants k, x0 such that g(x) <= k * f(x) for x >= x0

Suppose h(x) = O(f(x) + 1). This means there exist constants k1, x1 such that
h(x) <= k1 * (f(x) + 1) for all x >= x1

or h(x) <= k1 * f(x) + k1 for all x >= x1

If we have g(x) monotonically increasing and if we think that h(x1) - g(x0) could get to be greater than k1, we can say that g(x) = O(f(x) + 1).

Since lg(N) monotonically increases and has no upper bound we can assert that O(lg(N)) and O(lg(N) + ) are the same and one bound is not really stronger than the other.